# Iterating and filtering with ES6/lodash

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

We have an array of objects like:

```
const persons = [{
    name: "john",
    age: 23
}, {
    name: "lisa",
    age: 43
}, {
    name: "jim",
    age: 101
}, {
    name: "bob",
    age: 67
}];
```

And an array of a attribute values of the objects in object

```
const names = ["lisa", "bob"]
```

How can we find persons with name in the names array using es6, like:

```
const filteredPersons = [{
    name: "lisa",
    age: 43
}, {
    name: "bob",
    age: 67
}];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*ES6*

Use `filter` function with predicate and in it check the existence of the name in the `names` array.

```js
const persons = [
    {name: "john", age:23},
    {name: "lisa", age:43},
    {name: "jim", age:101},
    {name: "bob", age:67}
];

const names = ["lisa", "bob"];

const filtered = persons.filter(person => names.includes(person.name));

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: @dandavis It just compares the whole word. But it fits exactly the requirement.

Comment: @dandavis it just compares the words. `includes` related to the array, not the string. Don't be confused. Is array includes that word? - this way

Comment: doh!, sorry, it's past my bedtime.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`inlcudes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to get required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const persons = [{
  name: "john",
  age: 23
}, {
  name: "lisa",
  age: 43
}, {
  name: "jim",
  age: 101
}, {
  name: "bob",
  age: 67
}];
const names = ["lisa", "bob"];

console.log(persons.filter(({
  name
}) => names.includes(name)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use `indexOf` as `includes` does not work in IE browser. Also, using `{name}` works as Destructuring assignment that will hold the value of `name` property of the object.

```js
const persons = [{
  name: "john",
  age: 23
}, {
  name: "lisa",
  age: 43
}, {
  name: "jim",
  age: 101
}, {
  name: "bob",
  age: 67
}];
const names = ["lisa", "bob"];

console.log(persons.filter(({name}) => names.indexOf(name) !== -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

*lodash*

You can try following

```js
const persons = [{name: "john", age: 23},
    {name: "lisa",age: 43}, 
    {name: "jim", age: 101}, 
    {name: "bob",age: 67}];


const names = ["lisa", "bob"]


const filteredPersons = _.filter(persons, function(person) {
    return _.indexOf(names, person.name) !== -1;
});

console.log(filteredPersons);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to perform it in `n` complexity, here is a way to do it:

1. Create a map with key as person's name and value as person's object.
2. Map the criteria array and extract the person objects from the map create in step 1.

Here is a working demo:

```js
const persons = [{
  name: "john",
  age: 23
}, {
  name: "lisa",
  age: 43
}, {
  name: "jim",
  age: 101
}, {
  name: "bob",
  age: 67
}];

const names = ["lisa", "bob"];
const map = persons.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.name] = item;
  return acc;
}, {});
const result = names.map(name => map[name]);
console.log(result);
```

Note: This solution assumes that only unique person names are in the source array. It needs to be tweaked to handle duplicates.

Comment: You could achieve equivalent `time complexity` if you were to `reduce` the `names` and `filter` the `persons`. Such a strategy would also allow multiple `persons` to share the same `name` without being `overwritten`.

Comment: @ArmanCharan -- umm, I didn't get you quite right. Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Your current strategy achieves `O(n*m)` complexity but focuses on `hash tabling` the `persons` rather than `names`. As you noted: this means there can't be `multiple persons` with the `same name`. If you `hash` the `names` instead: your algorithm will have the same `time complexity` and be able to handle `multiple people` with the `same name`. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49872088/5566355).

Answer (score 1):

See [`Closures`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), and [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) for more info.

```js
// Input.
const persons = [{name: "john",age: 23}, {name: "lisa",age: 43}, {name: "jim",age: 101}, {name: "bob",age: 67}]
const names = ["lisa", "bob"]

// Filter.
const filter = (A, B) => (s => A.filter(x => s.has(x.name)))(new Set(B))

// Output.
const output = filter(persons, names)

// Proof.
console.log(output)
```